# Cleaning up a JSON object that is full of objects with 1 attribute

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that's formatted like the following:

```
{
    "ATTR1": {
        "0":"Value1"
    },
    "ATTR2": {
        "0":"Value2"
    } //and so on
}
```

and this format holds for dozens of attributes. I'm looking for a way to have the JSON be more like:

```
{
    "ATTR1": "Value1",
    "ATTR2": "Value2" //and so on
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Javascript? I've tried something like:

```
for(var attr in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        attr = attr[0];
    }
}
```

But this hasn't been working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the schema predictable?  Seems like a bit of a scary thing to do arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mutate the original `obj`, you can do this:

```
for(var attr in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        obj[attr] = obj[attr][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this solution as it mutates the original object and is closest to what I already have.

Answer (score 2):

Use reduce on the object's keys for that:

```js
let foo = {
    "ATTR1": {
        "0":"Value1"
    },
    "ATTR2": {
        "0":"Value2"
    } //and so on
};

let res = Object.keys(foo).reduce((a,b) => {
 a[b] = foo[b]['0'];
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I would just do `['0']`, but basically what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

you are close!

Try something like this:

```
var obj = {
    "ATTR1": {
        "0":"Value1"
    },
    "ATTR2": {
        "0":"Value2"
    } //and so on
};
var obj2 = {};
for(var attr in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        obj2[attr] = obj[attr][0];
    }
}


alert(JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/coLxfeum/

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over javascript objects is easier using Object.keys(), IMO.  It's supported in the major browsers...  Anyway, you want to iterate over the top level object, grabbing all of it's "smallObject" values and flatten them.  You can make the checks as strict as you like (insisting on "0" keys etc), but fundamentally, it seems important that the values you are collapsing are single-value objects containing string values?  Anyway - here's how you could do that:

```
var v1 = {
    "ATTR1": {
        "0": "Value1"
    },
    "ATTR2": {
        "0": "Value2"
    }
}

function flatten(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach( function(attr) {
        var smallObj = obj[attr];
        var keys = Object.keys(smallObj);
        if( keys.length === 1 && typeof smallObj[keys[0]] === 'string' ) {  // && keys[0] === "0" ?
            obj[attr] = smallObj[keys[0]];
        } // else throw Error(...) ?
    })
    return obj;
}

console.log(flatten(v1));

> { ATTR1: 'Value1', ATTR2: 'Value2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "ATTR1": {
        "0":"Value1"
    },
    "ATTR2": {
        "0":"Value2"
    }
};

var newJson = {};
for(var i = 0;i<Object.keys(jsonObj).length;i++) {
  newJson[Object.keys(jsonObj)[i]] = jsonObj[Object.keys(jsonObj)[i]]["0"];
}

console.log(newJson);
```